# rails joins query over has_many objects independently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have parent model `Project` & children model `ToDo`.

A project has many `ToDos` with column `starts_at` & `ends_at`.

I would like to search for projects that have 'any' todos in the time range.

Here I wrote some codes, however, it is not as expected.

```
class Project
   has_many :todos

   scope :active, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at < '#{Time.now}' AND todos.ends_at > '#{Time.now}'").distinct}
   scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where.not("todos.starts_at < '#{Time.now}' AND todos.ends_at > '#{Time.now}'").distinct}
   scope :done, -> {where("project_due > ?", Time.now)}
end
```

Active one seems right, but waiting scope also contains the projects that have more than one todos.

I wonder if there any solution to compare `starts_at` & `ends_at` per each todo. Not like above.

Thanks ahead.

***# Update ***

This is what I wanna achieve. but in one query.

```
scope :waiting, -> { joins(:todos).where.not(id: active.ids).where('finishing > ?', Time.now).distinct }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following

**Update**

For waiting you mean `starts_at` greater than `NOW` right? then it will be

```
scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at >= ?", Time.now).distinct}
```

If the match with the first condition then you don't need to match the second condition, you can write with the second condition like this

```
scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at > '#{Time.now}' AND todos.ends_at > '#{Time.now}'").distinct}
```

but don't need.

**Update 2**

Remove the `not` from `where`, here `not` means `active`

```
scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at >= ?", Time.now).distinct}
```

**Update 3 after Update 2 worked**

```
scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at >= ?", Time.now).distinct}
scope :finished, -> {where("finishing > ?", Time.now).distinct}
scope :waiting_n_progress, -> {where.not(id: active.ids).finished.waiting}
```

the `waiting_n_progress` scope, I think you will get your goal, remember that's not tested.

Hope it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is scope :waiting. active one works just fine.

Comment: @AstroLee see the ***Update***

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately updated query also returns some projects that is active && waiting some todos at the same time. I need to achieve projects that does not have any active todos at the moment And waiting for todos coming up.

Comment: @AstroLee try `scope :waiting, -> {joins(:todos).where("todos.starts_at >= ?", Time.now).distinct}` it should work see ***Update 2***

Comment: query works awesomely however also returning projects that does have progressing todo as well. I only wanna achieve projects that has 'some todos awaiting' and at the same time 'no todos currently progressing'. Thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean by `no todos currently progressing` I mean what's the logic, value or consept

Comment: Sorry for the confuse. I meant. Project A has [1 todo started yesterday and ends tmrw, 1 todo starts next monday and ends next thursday ]. Project B has only [1 todo starts next monday and ends next thursday]. I am trying to find projects like B but querying returns A also.

Comment: I added some #Update. please refer.

Comment: Hey @AstroLee, I think you achieved your initial goal, I mean which for you have posted this question e.g `waiting` scope, I have written***Update 3 after Update 2 worked*** see this if it doesn't work then you need to ask a new question for only this otherwise it little be confusing, what actually problem. I think you get it :)

Comment: It's ok, that's why I love this site so much, everyday learning new things,  you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query for waiting basically translate from `!(start < now && end > now)` to this `start >= now || end <= now` which would most likely return a lot more projects than you wanted. See if that is the logic that you wanted.

Also, for best Rails practices, you should write query like the user fool-dev suggested in the other answer using question mark. This is to prevent SQL injection as explained in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529335/2067598)

**EDIT**
So I think you mean waiting means projects that does not have any Todo or those that have awaiting Todo (`start_at > now`). I think this should work:

```
scope(:waiting) { includes(:todos).where('todos.project_id IS NULL OR todos.start_at > ?', Time.now).distinct }
```

The first part is to select projects that doesn't have any Todo and the second part is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I am getting a lot more projects than I wanted. I am still confused how I should achieve my goal. I wanna get projects that does not have any ongoing todos which are also not over yet while still have coming up todos.

Comment: + sql injection tip helped a lot. You really save me. I never knew such thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: so you just want projects that have todos that are all `end < now` or projects that have no Todos?

Comment: I wanna get projects, that has 'some todos awaiting' and at the same time 'no todos currently progressing'

Comment: then you can do `where(joins(:todos).where("(todos.starts_at >= ? OR todos.ends_at <= ?) AND finishing > ?", Time.now, Time.now, Time.now)`. I believe this is the only way, and unfortunately yes, you have to duplicate the code for `active` scope.